# What is the general form of the naturals numbers that have a divisor beyond 1 and himself?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

> The question is:
>
> What is the general form of the natural numbers that have :
>
> a) a divisor beyond 1 and himself?
>
> b) a number prime of divisors?

For letter a) I know that when a number has two divisors, 1 and himself we define him as prime otherwise he is composite. But I don't understand what form general this question is asking, how I can to write this?
For letter b) I think that, if I can answer the letter a) I will answer the letter b).

Comment: Hint for b: If $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_m^{a_m}$ is the prime factorization of $n$ then the number of divisors of $n$ is $(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\cdots(a_m+1)$.

Comment: $b):$ Numbers having a number of divisors being a prime number must be prime powers. $a):$ These are the composite numbers. In the general prime factorization we have more than one prime factor and/or an exponent exceeding $1$

Comment: @Peter So, for the letter **a)** I can write as the general form n = a*b, when a,b $\in N$, 1 < a,b < n. Then a is a divisor of n different of 1 and of himself?

Comment: @JulianaRodrigues Yes, exactly the way to write down the general number. For $b)$ , you can write down $p^{q-1}$ with primes $p$ and $q$ (not necessarily distinct)

Comment: @Peter Thank you a lot for your help.